# Hide some tables in SQL Server 2014 Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to hide (and show) some tables in object explorer of SQL Server 2014? Actually there are repetitive log tables which are prefixed with actual table. I want to hide them temporarily. Also when needed I want to show them back.

Comment: where you want to hide and show table in browser or else..?

Comment: In object explorer

Comment: in which language..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use extended properties

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

Above code hides person.address table

If you want to revert,below is the code

```
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

**References:**
[Hiding tables in SSMS Object Explorer](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/04/03/hiding-tables-in-ssms-object-explorer-using-extended-properties/)

You also can use below to deny viewing any user particular schema or table in object explorer,but this doesn't work when user is of higher role like db_owner..

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON Schema.Table TO UserName;
```

Comment: Right. Thanks. Isn't there any GUI way?

Comment: @SajjadAbdullah: You can't hide it through GUI,as there is no UI for this extended event

Answer (score 1):

try this one

if you want to `hide table` use this one

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

and `show table` use this one

```
EXEC sp_dropextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = 'Person',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = 'Address';
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an extended property which will hide the table:

```
EXEC sp_addextendedproperty
@name = N'microsoft_database_tools_support',
@value = 'Hide',
@level0type = N'Schema', @level0name = '**YOUR SCHEMA**',
@level1type = N'Table', @level1name = '**YOUR TABLE NAME**';
GO
```